# Can I have a "coefficient" like interpretation of my y-axis in a mgcv::gam.plot()?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I had already read some interesting alternatives to interpret the `plot(mymodel)` from a `gam` fit like in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430606/make-nonlinear-smooth-interpretable-in-logistic-gam-regression).

```
# Data
dd <- structure(list(GDP = c(30515, 19725, 35894, 17305, 9867, 15214, 
43142, 13934, 56774, 25288, 44636, 28935, 43253, 23625, 25837, 
31116, 27862, 16556, 16190, 25195, 14986, 68933, 26267, 20440, 
21746, 14986, 30447, 21710, 42224, 15095, 16263, 25024, 31002, 
32848, 43761, 33176, 13792, 23625, 16808, 41057, 37892, 20492, 
34935, 29958, 34454, 73465, 18060, 39449, 25776, 31777, 46402, 
15623, 29712, 21008, 36198, 25024, 33176, 18778, 41175, 25024, 
31988, 17725, 24179, 13504, 77617, 14269, 26825, 24375, 16580, 
44448, 19523, 24515, 25039, 16730, 37844, 16318, 62974, 20693, 
16810, 18255, 30614, 27727, 16611, 23625, 35383, 20355, 36502, 
50673, 24552, 30495, 20492, 11768, 14413, 20120, 44398, 23072, 
19668, 25189, 16355, 37361, 27216, 28597, 45313, 27216, 19653, 
76194, 11902, 34292, 36800, 18778, 57664, 60916, 29712, 18368, 
11611, 14280, 34631, 12135, 27737, 23825, 35751, 44606, 32497, 
15095, 29658, 31021, 21209, 10060, 15132, 47559, 44835, 27081, 
31777, 11442, 39756, 12565, 16093, 25794, 58756, 24383, 23815, 
22555, 9073, 23031, 34812, 25895, 13934, 36892, 28638, 12606, 
31116, 17963, 25749, 23072, 29509, 44835, 46843, 12285, 18688, 
30305, 43761, 50624, 24515, 27595, 21799, 17298, 25794, 19425, 
18868, 26779, 32437, 25438, 43253, 15523, 20436, 29302, 41583, 
38833, 44443, 20324, 18578, 36462, 23329, 14269, 15479, 15214, 
17465, 19704, 13305, 23075, 32776, 15623, 10918, 44587, 24671, 
8478, 11442, 33828, 35383, 27749), Wage = c(0, 21897.3005962264, 
18098.1013668886, 5721.51105263158, 0, 0, 0, 14376.0889184, 38547.9376727447, 
17722.3549873251, 17110.1706479156, 0, 142309.937, 0, 0, 42446.4695569812, 
0, 9613.13095508445, 0, 0, 4141.19977411764, 17680.2982901078, 
23437.8599580815, 0, 0, 26661.2739361382, 21078.9864430457, 0, 
70395.4781485715, 0, 0, 39602.1593640719, 21353.1996631231, 0, 
0, 31263.1240312159, 0, 0, 16742.3629381408, 30609.4028735632, 
0, 0, 143039.443786666, 11689.0115524349, 37346.9720513089, 160378.6592375, 
0, 0, 0, 27964.3515373334, 4435.205225, 0, 23691.7178206271, 
10859.1139584504, 30671.1090078788, 0, 30790.622685, 0, 22302.4321223963, 
7951.11867047619, 0, 7171.93619768519, 66602.2565076336, 0, 104196.074399216, 
0, 15442.7193010811, 23293.1851001307, 0, 0, 25831.393328, 0, 
21359.02725, 0, 8050.588616, 16338.1106, 2579.6373062069, 0, 
15948.3485306372, 0, 20361.5500836544, 31677.6394032, 0, 12564.0154095238, 
35821.580462963, 36947.9503866666, 25300.8266651163, 45732.7877231373, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20482.8640638462, 12747.1747921875, 41477.654, 
0, 23700.4572205275, 0, 0, 20606.6365738378, 0, 16877.7788716709, 
18479.6474883721, 0, 2633.61414059406, 0, 31657.6492790697, 212166.588333333, 
0, 35460.0238402204, 3868.9808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22129.6907649569, 
30046.8504292683, 14410.4145120514, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11575.0498309424, 
39037.0514451477, 0, 29708.3057267846, 25378.712632653, 0, 0, 
16621.9704982911, 39704.0317835294, 0, 14930.805379836, 43284.495181337, 
0, 0, 0, 15037.2481154986, 0, 16921.2017315598, 19875.7748910244, 
21389.2608662444, 0, 135229.170095384, 0, 0, 22787.2578523466, 
14343.1388662444, 16381.7273025584, 33001.9426123596, 20879.5439641899, 
0, 0, 21767.370135849, 29353.1834862035, 22868.1726857143, 19266.8150472126, 
15907.7118561494, 14654.5679873171, 24638.5213278535, 290769.262608, 
0, 14570.2077740541, 22646.471631356, 0, 95517.8176422765, 19878.7632243161, 
14698.958974353, 24720.8489643781, 28625.2423755036, 32259.2125263604, 
28017.9849961773, 0, 13508.1738694762, 29150.2506749763, 0, 17556.1824878261, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15584.3064931477, 31537.3301848598, 0, 0, 0, 17668.4740558409, 
0, 23652.4630510345, 120560.601746666, 0, 0), Impostos = c(258226.676256, 
7666065, 3109820.88922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1422423.021272, 4934817.705125, 
1483048.940481, 7077441.931609, 5820.292305, 222079.463375, 659.22175, 
83585.1555, 320840.867347, 12152.633423, 1539360.423536, 9581.325835, 
111399.905589, 0, 21796324.291819, 2928394.5999, 17332.849282, 
2498.140128, -573250.033617, 1157166.42008, 15769.690384, 421808.68674, 
0, 183157.899205, 3328234.468041, 5682789.587699, 5006.299375, 
18268.75023, 104737934.0823, 33089.171395, 2791.401448, 1556758.5678, 
0, 111876.46437, 121321.9722, 258226.676256, 2414974.36635, 916062.9081, 
1975036.28904, 1561224.230828, 0, 0, 0, 454954.02975, 31272.05675, 
5084207.455964, 2422543.905098, 1724820.238501, 397492.156583, 
0, 0, 5755422.61052, 0, 0, 1034.491323, 3530226.1995, 0, 1124309.586451, 
0, 874523.528256, 269120.645112, 4328.002768, 2552.270875, 3640.803141, 
40462.97585, 199884.6179, 573.356233, 40544.727907, 72871.686048, 
206343.844042, 75328.7612, 470901.68573, 692158.443962, 5587374.731822, 
0, 232664.557057, 123364.091224, 2019102.652875, 2170.593684, 
1265.561115, 328343.671061, 50817.086913, 0, 70457.29152, 2094.3065, 
111137.169717, 121950.321528, -116001.32229, 3725.8628, 0, 6175891.538784, 
0, 0, 12252018.137656, 5556.082658, 33425581.032815, 6148657.88515, 
341115.8817, 199270.51344, 1034010.912088, 5164601.75, 0, 32833.799152, 
6983242.94025, 391597.461504, 209116.513305, 3995.909141, 0, 
5130.959856, 501898.121985, 0, 218487.286927, 19818.939585, 6300922.482113, 
1054770.174555, 26308690.90355, 0, 454761.440923, 19771.560761, 
9190.036619, 0, 90784.561846, 4743249.903283, 1510454.994125, 
0, 91898751.0203, 0, 0, 0, 1023339.879699, 831.7556, 31683.9215, 
5400542.827929, 4912558.07262, 1255764.09219, 72295.526989, 1576276.2015, 
31291270.907688, 8543.72812, 332443.0835, 832474.902846, 3174089.285538, 
42774.207855, 111399.905589, 83105.83931, 22407.841904, 62756859.66, 
5031482.235648, 2850166.33825, 444017.09275, 1049166.784934, 
24371.831533, 279939.808095, 250419.056385, 7294100.376346, 173702.71985, 
6123401.138575, 2852782.779528, 617556.403032, 50243018.9536, 
0, 4000.7068, 614062.662561, 517729.799125, 11713.290821, 558763.695875, 
178316.056032, 175401.966415, 356368.180205, 13540021.831425, 
1919305.031347, 11104163.28175, 5738.614963, 1853842.915983, 
9680024.6557, 10546.207868, 175374.182494, 519945.056939, 0, 
120.188278, 0, 1324929.539352, 926744.526451, 667209.782967, 
6392.842544, 0, 54088.93473, 2155260.814341, 349.713712, 3573533.041848, 
191109.153862, 347176.339125, 191109.153862)), row.names = c(480L, 
127L, 454L, 156L, 152L, 173L, 342L, 208L, 571L, 485L, 313L, 549L, 
578L, 176L, 587L, 317L, 365L, 69L, 111L, 358L, 95L, 323L, 307L, 
349L, 243L, 62L, 187L, 366L, 500L, 166L, 282L, 306L, 253L, 610L, 
542L, 373L, 53L, 237L, 63L, 553L, 548L, 154L, 456L, 332L, 499L, 
524L, 466L, 609L, 460L, 407L, 181L, 183L, 328L, 80L, 381L, 401L, 
468L, 168L, 205L, 400L, 408L, 77L, 563L, 105L, 402L, 42L, 363L, 
198L, 417L, 603L, 102L, 171L, 134L, 107L, 479L, 31L, 364L, 175L, 
20L, 422L, 379L, 346L, 118L, 209L, 560L, 41L, 529L, 36L, 471L, 
426L, 215L, 162L, 32L, 26L, 525L, 163L, 533L, 188L, 350L, 159L, 
192L, 336L, 247L, 131L, 179L, 547L, 222L, 551L, 577L, 229L, 510L, 
303L, 354L, 60L, 44L, 457L, 545L, 112L, 362L, 539L, 314L, 503L, 
125L, 227L, 423L, 412L, 478L, 91L, 99L, 266L, 555L, 37L, 312L, 
136L, 281L, 33L, 269L, 285L, 601L, 268L, 502L, 544L, 56L, 588L, 
186L, 488L, 147L, 453L, 267L, 122L, 334L, 287L, 351L, 129L, 191L, 
576L, 564L, 86L, 49L, 415L, 514L, 327L, 133L, 318L, 196L, 302L, 
190L, 272L, 121L, 270L, 607L, 477L, 561L, 67L, 87L, 259L, 497L, 
442L, 558L, 279L, 74L, 429L, 355L, 6L, 361L, 234L, 356L, 277L, 
283L, 65L, 320L, 244L, 289L, 534L, 264L, 106L, 197L, 395L, 598L, 
419L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a `gam` model with `Gamma` link function:

```
library(mgcv)
m2 <- gam(GDP ~ s(Wage) +
                s(Impostos),
          data = dd, 
          select = T,
          family = Gamma(link = "log"),
          method = "REML")
```

And I plot it:

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     xlab = "Wage",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

I usually interpret as:

Up to Wage 200000 there is an increase in the log of GDP, and after that a decrease up to 300000, and after that, there is no change (because 0 crosses the shaded area).

However, can I say how much is the increase? Like, up to Wage 200000 there is an increase in the log of GDP of a little bit more than .5 (value in the y-axis) compared to Wage around 1500 ? (hard to tell by the scale of the graphic if the Wage that crosses 0 on y-axis is 1500)
I am looking for interpretation-like regression coefficients.

If I exponentiate my y-axis I would get:

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     trans = exp,
     xlab = "Wage",
     ylab = "Change of GDP")
```

[image]

Can I say that up to Wage 100000 there is an almost 50% increase (compared to low value of Wage that on y-axis crosses 1)?

---

Addition (1): Added graphics with `log1p(Wage)`

The results are still weird because at least 40% of the data is zero:

```
> quantile(dd$Wage, probs = seq(0,1,.1))
       0%       10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%       70% 
     0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00   8831.86  16355.56  21161.25 
      80%       90%      100% 
 25997.37  36987.85 290769.26
```

Maybe should I do something else?

```
m2 <- gam(GDP ~ s(log1p(Wage)) +
            s(Impostos),
          data = dd, 
          select = T,
          family = Gamma(link = "log"),
          method = "REML")
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     xlab = "Wage",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     trans = exp,
     xlab = "Wage",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

---

Addition (2): Added graphics with `sqrt(Wage+.1)`

```
m2 <- gam(GDP ~ s(sqrt(Wage+.1)) +
            s(Impostos),
          data = dd, 
          select = T,
          family = Gamma(link = "log"),
          method = "REML")
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     xlab = "Sqrt(Wage+.1)",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image])

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     trans = exp,
     xlab = "Sqrt(Wage+.1)",
     ylab = "Change of GDP")
```

[image]

---

Addition (2) : Added graphics with `rank(Wage)`

Note how the interpretation changes in the end compared to the first graphic. It happens because the extreme values join with the less extreme values. I don't know how usual it is this, but I think that it is an option.

The %Dev. Explained with only `s(rank(Wage))` is 19.6%, with `s(Wage)` is 16.2%, `s(log(Wage+.1))` is 15.3% and `s(sqrt(Wage+.1))` is 21.5%. I am not sure if I should change the transformation based on the %Dev. Explained (I think that it may help).

```
m2 <- gam(GDP ~ s(rank(Wage)),
          data = dd, 
          select = T,
          family = Gamma(link = "log"),
          method = "REML")
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     xlab = "Rank(Wage)",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     trans = exp,
     xlab = "Rank(Wage)",
     ylab = "Change of GDP")
```

[image]

---

Addition (3): Added graphics with `s(Wage, by = PAID)` WITH `% Dev. explained = 18.4%`

```
dd$PAID <- factor(with(dd, Wage>0), 
                  labels = c("Não", "Sim"),
                  levels = c(F,T))
levels(dd$PAID)
"Não" "Sim"
m2 <- gam(GDP ~ s(Wage, by = PAID),
          data = dd, 
          select = T,
          family = Gamma(link = "log"),
          method = "REML")
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 1,
     xlab = "Wage (not PAID)",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

```
plot(m2, shade = T, se = T, select = 2,
     xlab = "Wage (PAID)",
     ylab = "Change in log of GDP")
```

[image]

What I did not understand from this transformation, was that the smooth was made for all range of `Wage` even for those who are not `PAID`. And for those who were `PAID`, there is no effect at all

Comment: You should probably log transform `Wage` as most of the range of the covariate is covered by only a few observations and hence most of your basis functions are being defined by these few observations

Comment: I understand your concern. I tried that but the researcher was not happy with that because he would lose the direct interpretation, and I have too many zero's. But can I still interpret the y-axis as change in the average of log(Y)?

Comment: The rug plot doesn't suggest you have too many zero wages, but just do `log1p(Wage)`, It's a bit of a moot point to discuss interpretation of the smooth effect of `Wage` on the response when that's the function you have fitted - it's largely defined by 3 observations with extreme wages

Comment: I included the graphics with `log`,  but I forgot to change the `x-label`

Comment: It looks like the log is too strong; try square root, but that actual 0 is going to cause some issues regardless. The idea is to try to spread out your observations but the 0 wage is going to be an issue. Could you break this up into a paid/not-paid and then have the smooth only for those individuals that are paid?

Comment: Tks for your attention! I also tried to use `kmeans` for a variable similar to this one. However, the clustered variable explains less the response variable in terms of %Dev. explained compared to original variable. How could I "smooth only for those individuals that are paid"? (discarding those who are not paid?). A piecewise linear regression I don't think it is an options, because the covariate is already "piecewise". The main problem is the large distance between covariate values. I included the results of `sqrt(Wage+.1)` and s(rank(Wage)) (the last may be a solution).

Comment: Included! If you prefer, we can use the chat too later

Comment: You would do `s(Wage, by = PAID == TRUE)` I think? I'd need to check. Anyway, the answer to your original question is that yes, you can state the things you said (change in log response, or % change in response if you use `trans = exp`), but you shouldn't state that there is no change after wage 30000. The estimated function is a declining effect on the response, it's just really uncertain. I'm not convinced the rank is a good way to go as you're loosing a lot of information.

Comment: Tks for your kind help! I added your last suggestion in the question (I made a question too). I said that there is no change after wage 30000 regarding the statistical significance. But indeed there is a decrease in the mean of response. Am I interpreting correctly with these considerations?).